# Find a non vanishing differential form on the torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449975/pulling-back-forms-computation)
I attempted to pull back the 2-form $dt\wedge ds \in \bigwedge^2(\Bbb R^2)$ using the product of the stereographic projections. I'd like to have my calculations checked, for I have the faintest idea of what I'm doing here.

I'll just report the pull back by $\phi:S^1\times S^1 \setminus \{(0,1,0,1)\} \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ with
$$\phi(x,y,z,w) = \left(\frac{x}{1-y},\frac{z}{1-w}\right)$$
Now, knowing that $\phi^*$ commutes with the wedge product and $d$ I got:
$$\phi^*(dt\wedge ds) = d\left(\frac{x}{1-y}\right)\wedge d\left(\frac{z}{1-w}\right) = \left(\frac{dx}{1-y} + \frac{xdy}{(1-y)^2}\right)\wedge \left(\frac{dz}{1-w} + \frac{zdw}{(1-w)^2}\right)$$
then expanding everything by linearity of $\wedge$. This form is non vanishing on $S^1\times S^1$ because $dt\wedge ds$ is non vanishing on $\Bbb R^2$ right?

Comment: Do you want just any non-vanishing differential form at all? Why are you not happy with $\operatorname{d}\!\theta_1\wedge \operatorname{d}\!\theta_2$ (the natural volume form)?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I'm perfectly happy with it, I'd just like to have my reslut checked. Is it true that $\phi^*(dt\wedge ds)$ is non vanishing becuse $dt\wedge ds$ is? Is this a legitimate way of pulling back differential forms using charts?

Comment: Actually your map $\phi$ is not well-defined on a larger set: the domain should be $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1\setminus\{ y=1 \text{ or } w=1\}$.